# A planet inside out

Tags: planets, alternate-worlds, hollow-earth

I've had this dream tonight about a planet that is Earth but inside out. The outside of the planet are rocks, stone, a surface like that of the moon. There a few holes that tunnel through the surface and lead to the inside. There in the center is a tiny sun. On the inside surface everything is like on Earth.

What would this world be like? Can such a world exist?

Comment: Questions about this kind of world are so common, WB has a tag for the category! Take your pick: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hollow-earth

Comment: You said "tiny sun." Depending on how big that gets, you might also be dreaming of a Dyson Sphere. Again... a tag: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dyson-spheres

Comment: I'm not good at interpreting dream but that world you are describing isn't stable and an unstable world can't exist, if it does it won't look anything like Earth!

Comment: Voting too broad, because it is too broad to pick one question and mark duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you had a dream about the [hollow earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_Earth).

there can be caves, but not a complete shell. Gravity and entropy will crumble such a planet into its lowest energy configuration.

Comment: What if gravity was virtual?

Comment: @SovereignSun: What is "virtual gravity"?

Comment: @AlexP Created by human

Comment: Definition of virtual: 1.  Existing or resulting in essence or effect though not in actual fact, form, or name: the virtual extinction of the buffalo.

2.  Existing in the mind, especially as a product of the imagination. Used in literary criticism of a text.

Comment: created by human is artificial, but still it will crumble down any shell on the long run

Answer (score 1):

Or you had a dream about a [Dyson Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere)

For your inhabitants on the inside it would look like a hollow earth with a sun at the centre.

---

Can such a world exist?

As of human technology in 2017. No.